# Android Toast notification is too small in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Has anyone had any problems with the Toast Notifications in Ice Cream Sandwich being too small?  In my application, the notifications look fine on all other versions.  In Ice Cream Sandwich, however, its incredibly tiny.  At first I thought that it might be my custom theme but, after disabling it, I saw the same results.  I am displaying a Toast just like everyone else with:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Hello, World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My theme:

```
<resources>
<style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/blue_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/White</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: i suppose you already cleaned an rebuilded the project right?

Comment: Yes, it is still the same after cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I've also seen applications running on 4.0 where the Toast notifications appear just fine.

Comment: Have you tried making a custom Toast.

Comment: I have not tried making a custom Toast, but I'd rather not go that route.  Instead, I want to try to figure out what is wrong with the default Toast...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794519/toast-size-on-galaxy-nexus) question/answer:

> Adding

```
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

> to my manifest, solved my problem...