# Toast very small on JellyBean

Tags: android, toast

I know question is same as this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658059/android-toast-notification-is-too-small-in-ice-cream-sandwich/9236009#9236009). 
But my question is added to it The answer @Nick gave might be right I just want to know where to add that in `manifest`.

Comment: Add it before application tag in manifest.

Comment: thanks chirag!! I added but its giving error I mentioned below in comment. Any other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add support screen code in your `manifest.xml`

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.XXX.XXXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

// Paste support screen code here.
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. actually my <min-sdk_version> is 3. and this is giving error in manifest when I build. errors are        error: No resource identifier found for **attribute 'normalScreens' in package 'android' 
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'android' 
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizeable' in package 'android' 
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'smallScreens' in package 'android'**

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html), you must place this directly under `<manifest>`

> contained in:
>   `<manifest>`

Comment: thanks for the answer Damien.I tried from document but its showing error thats why asked here

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I was using Android 1.5 which doesn't support {supports-screen} . this is supported above Android 1.6 I did it and thus the toast automatically showed in normal size. Thanks all of you for your answers. Thanks MurliGaneshan for your code to let me know